# Deep linking scheme cannot be processed correctly?

Tags: android, deep-linking

We use deeplinking to open our app by customer. Our scheme is customized like `mozatfoo`, and our url is `mozatfoo://video/335477/1502489665013698`. 
This url can be used to open our app correctly with `adb` command like:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d mozatfoo://video/335477/1502489665013698
```

But when we use Appsflyer to integrate our deeplinking functions, we found that scheme and url is changed:

```
intent://video/1449937/1502363982400417?media_source=Test#Intent;scheme=mozatloops;package=mozat.rings.loops;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=mozat.rings.loops&referrer=af_tranid%253DFg_WOxRqK7cNq7j7YR1AUg%2526pid%253DTest%2526c%253Dshare_code%2526af_dp%253Dmozatfoo%253A%252F%252Fvideo%252F1449937%252F1502363982400417%252Fst01;S.market_referrer=af_tranid%3DFg_WOxRqK7cNq7j7YR1AUg%26pid%3DTest%26c%3Dshare_code%26af_dp%3Dmozatloops%3A%2F%2Fvideo%2F1449937%2F1502363982400417%2Fst01;end
```

This url can not invoke our app. My question is:

1. Can Android system recognize `intent://` scheme?
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, how android process url with `intent://` scheme?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can Android system recognize `intent://` scheme?

Yes it does.

> 2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, how android process url with `intent://` scheme?

It processes it as regular uri and replaces the scheme with the one contained in the `intent://` uri.
These uri are often called Chrome Intents since they were first introduced here.

See documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

And the corresponding source code of uri parsing is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#5068